# C++ : Check if the template type is one of the variadic template types

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, variadic-templates, c++17

Let's say we have function:

```
template <typename Kind, typename... Kinds> void foo(){...};
```

What is the simplest way to check if the type 'Kind' is one of the types 'Kinds' in C++ (including C++1z)?

Comment: This particular question has been asked at least three times in the past few days...

Answer (score 24):

You could use the following type trait:

```
template <typename...>
struct is_one_of {
    static constexpr bool value = false;
};

template <typename F, typename S, typename... T>
struct is_one_of<F, S, T...> {
    static constexpr bool value =
        std::is_same<F, S>::value || is_one_of<F, T...>::value;
};
```

[**Live Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8091582939a960cc)

**Update C++17**

Using the C++17 pattern expansion there is no need for auxiliar class anymore

```
template <typename Kind, typename... Kinds> void foo(){
    /* The following expands to :
     * std::is_same_v<Kind, Kind0> || std::is_same_v<Kind, Kind1> || ... */
    if constexpr ((std::is_same_v<Kind, Kinds> || ...)) {
        // expected type
    } else {
        // not expected type
    }
};
```

[**Live Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/76c8730e8f6a834d)