# Conversion and output operator for variant types and variadic templates

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, c++14, unions

I asked another question recently about this and I was wondering how one can go about providing a class with a structure as illustrated here https://gist.github.com/tibordp/6909880 with a conversion operator such as `operator string()`.  Basically the idea illustrated in the code is that of a union and a variant type.  With the union element being the object of type `data_t`.  Which is itself a typedef of `std::aligned_storage` with the appropriate classes.

In particular I am looking for a way to query the given templated classes and return the `static_cast`ed object.  If none of the types queried are correct then a static_assert should fail or a regular assert should fail.  I see that there is probably a way to go through the given templated classes and store their typeid().hash_code() in a set and then query that but that does not seem to not be the most efficient solution here.

So something like the following

```
template <typename... Vs>
struct variant {
    typename std::aligned_union<Types...>::type storage;
    int hash_code_of_type_stored;

    template <typename Type>
    operator Type() { 
        // static assert if the type is not in Vs... or assert fail
        // otherwise return the appropriate static_cast 
    }
};
```

This would be possible through having a assert that would compare the hash_code of the input type to the type of the object stored.  But then that is not satisfactory because I would like to somehow know the type of the object stored here so that for example I can overload the `operator<<` function for use with ostreams properly.

Also as a side note.  If you have an `operator string()` function defined on a custom struct that has a string as a member variable, then what is returned from the function?  It would only make sense for this to be a const reference but I wanted to make sure.

Comment: @Downvoter.  It is hard to provide a minimal, complete and verifiable example of code in a question where one is looking to find out how that code is written.  It would be great if you could suggest something else that I should do to make my question better.

Comment: A code sample of what you want to achieve is necessary though, compilable or not.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I tried to code what I was thinking.  Could you remove your downvote please?  I would love to get an answer here

Answer (score 1):

I recently implemented my own variadic template for checking if a certain type is within a parameter pack. I got to my solution with this answer from another SO user:

[Check if C++0x parameter pack contains a type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118541/check-if-c0x-parameter-pack-contains-a-type)

```
template <typename... Vs>
struct variant {
    typename std::aligned_union<Types...>::type storage;
    int hash_code_of_type_stored;

    template <typename Type>
    operator Type() { 
        static_assert(contains<Type, Vs...>::value, 
            "parameter pack should contain Type");
    }
};
```

Comment: That's awesome!  But could you let me know how contains is implemented?

Comment: Check out the link I provided: the accepted answer's author is using a variadic template. By recursively solving the parameter pack and letting the struct "contains" inherit from std's true_type or false_type. The "inheritance" is the clever part: std::conditional decides based on whether the current "unrolled" type is the same as the provided first one (in your case Type) or if there are more to enroll. In the first case, it inherits from true_type, otherwise it keeps "unrolling" the parameter pack until it reaches the end - and if that is different, it "returns" the false_type.

Comment: Thank you!  Would you know how the answer to this question also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36223247/how-operator-with-boostassert-is-implemented ?

Answer (score 1):

This is an implementation the variant type proposed in the Question.  It fixes some problems present in the initial, unfinished version:

- Added destruction, dispatched at runtime according to the currently stored value's type.
- Fixed incompatibilities under g++ which I overlooked because I use Visual Studio.  Let me know if you see any other compiler incompatibilities -- Microsoft's extensions will happily compile a lot of ill-formed templates which cause g++ to fail.
- Opted to store value data in an instantiated aligned_union member object
- Removed template metaprogram for finding max type size because aligned_union doesn't need this.  It accepts an alignment size parameter, but there is no alignment requirement here, so pass 0 for this parameter.
- Non-POD data may now be added to the variant, but you should fetch the stored value by casting to a reference to the type.  Casting to the type itself is likely to invoke one of its constructors, passing the variant object to it for conversion.  If the cast operators are marked explicit, this may remove the implicit conversions which cause the compiler to choose these unwanted constructors when deciding how to handle a cast from variant to one of its types.

I'm finished with this unless more compiler problems crop up.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <new>
#include <string>

namespace cvrnt {
// types_match works like std::is_same
template <typename T, typename U>
struct types_match {
    struct true_t { int x; };
    struct false_t { true_t x[2]; };
    template <typename A, typename B>
    static false_t test(const A&, const B&);
    template <typename A>
    static true_t  test(const A&, const A&);
    static constexpr bool value = sizeof(test(T{}, U{})) == sizeof(true_t);
};

template<bool condition, typename T=void> struct enable_if {};
template<class T>                         struct enable_if<true, T> { using type = T; };

// pack_index structs: searches parameter pack for a given type, giving index
template <typename T, int CURI, bool MATCH, typename V, typename ...Vs>
struct pack_index_helper {
    static constexpr int index = pack_index_helper<T, CURI + 1, types_match<T, V>::value, Vs...>::index;
};
template <typename T, int CURI, typename V>
struct pack_index_helper<T, CURI, false, V> {
    static constexpr int index = types_match<T, V>::value ? CURI - 1 : -1;
};
template <typename T, int CURI, typename V, typename ...Vs>
struct pack_index_helper<T, CURI, true, V, Vs...> {
    static constexpr int index = CURI - 1;
};
template <typename T, typename ...Vs>
struct pack_index {
    static constexpr int index = pack_index_helper<T, 0, false, Vs...>::index;
};

////

template <typename T, typename ...Vs>
struct type_in_pack {
    static constexpr bool value = pack_index<T, Vs...>::index >= 0;
};

// Curious' variant
template <typename ...Vs>
struct variant {
    // declare the aligned_union type for this parameter pack (from <type_traits>)
    // no special alignment requirement is specified here
    using union_t = typename std::aligned_union<0, Vs...>::type;
    static constexpr auto sizeof_storage = sizeof(union_t);

    // the "storage" object is used for storage of the variant's values
    // variant values.
    union_t   storage;
    // "stored_type_index" keeps track of the current stored type
    // >=0 indicates the stored value is valid and is of the type
    //     corresponding to this parameter pack index.
    // -1  indicates no value is currently stored
    int stored_type_index;

    // value data are stored in "storage" using placement new copy-construction
    // they are read using pointers, reinterpret_cast to the current type
    // the objects are destroyed with reinterpret_cast pointers, too
    // * Unsure about strict aliasing rule violation when "storage" is an aligned_union object.

    // this StoreValue overload handles non-pointer/non-array values
    template <typename T>
    void StoreValue(const T& value) {
        // throw -2 if storing non-pointer type does not match any pack type
        if((stored_type_index = pack_index<T, Vs...>::index) == -1) { throw - 2; }
        // placement construction
        new (&storage) T{ value };
    }
    // this overload handles pointer values and makes sure array references
    // are stored as decayed pointers
    template <typename T>
    void StoreValue(const T* pvalue) {
        // throw -3 if storing pointer type doesn't match any pack type
        if((stored_type_index = pack_index<T, Vs...>::index) == -1) { throw - 3; }
        // placement construction
        new (&storage) const T*(pvalue);
    }

    template <typename T>
    T& GetValue() {
        if(stored_type_index == -1 || stored_type_index != pack_index<T, Vs...>::index) {
            // GetValue attempted when no value stored, or when stored
            // type doesn't match this GetValue's template type
            throw(stored_type_index);
        }
        return *reinterpret_cast<T*>(&storage);
    }
    template <typename T>
    const T& GetValue() const {
        // use const_cast to leverage non-const version, to avoid duplicate code 
        return const_cast<const T&>(const_cast<variant*>(this)->GetValue<T>());
    }

    // Template conversion (cast) operators
    // Return const or non-const reference to stored value.
    // The parameter list only matches types from the variant's parameter pack
    // other possible conversions are disabled using enable_if and type_in_pack
    template <typename Type, typename=typename enable_if<type_in_pack<Type, Vs...>::value>::type>
    operator const Type& () const { return GetValue<Type>(); }
    template <typename Type, typename = typename enable_if<type_in_pack<Type, Vs...>::value>::type>
    operator Type& () { return GetValue<Type>(); }

    // Run-time dispatch of destructor by stored value type parameter index
    template <int index>
    void destroy_stored_object_helper() {
        // This overload's index is one past the end of the pack
        // It won't ever be used at runtime, but
        // it needs to be here in order to terminate
        // compile-time recursive pack iteration
        // when no parameters are left.
    }

    template <int index, typename T, typename ...Ts>
    void destroy_stored_object_helper() {
        if(stored_type_index == index) {
            // This version's pack index matches the
            // stored type index.  Destroy stored object, then
            // set stored type index to -1, indicating no value stored.
            reinterpret_cast<T*>(&storage)->~T();
            stored_type_index = -1;
        }
        else {
            // the function whose pack index matches "stored_type_index"
            // will be found later on, so call the next type's function.
            destroy_stored_object_helper<index + 1, Ts...>();
        }
    }
    // "destroy_stored_object" performs runtime destructor dispatch
    // for pack type at "stored_type_index"
    // No destructor is called when index is negative.
    void destroy_stored_object() {
        // skip destruction when no value currently stored
        if(stored_type_index < 0) return;
        // start the compile-time generated chain
        // of pack type destructor wrapper functions
        destroy_stored_object_helper<0, Vs...>();
        // this would be more efficient if implemented
        // as an indexed table
    }
    // assignment operator, from an element type
    // first makes sure any current value is destroyed
    // then stores the passed value
    template <typename T>
    variant& operator = (const T& src) {
        destroy_stored_object();
        StoreValue(src);
        return *this;
    }
    // assignment from variant could be added, but
    // deleted here so the template or default assignment won't
    // be used
    variant& operator = (const variant& src) = delete;

    // default ctor sets index to flag no value currently stored
    variant() : stored_type_index(-1) {}

    // Template conversion constructor
    template <typename T>
    variant(const T& src) { StoreValue(src); }

    // ok to implement copy ctor later
    // deleted here because default implementation is bad
    variant(const variant& src) = delete;

    // The move ctor is straightforward:
    // just copy the source object's member values
    // then set the source object's "stored_type_index"
    // to -1, which means there is no stored value
    variant(variant&& src) : storage(src.storage), stored_type_index(src.stored_type_index) {
        src.stored_type_index = -1;
    }

    ~variant() { destroy_stored_object(); }
};
}

int main() {
    try {
        // construct a variant object, initally storing an int value
        cvrnt::variant<int, std::string, double, const char*, char> my_variant(11);
        std::cout << static_cast<int>(my_variant) << '\n';

        // set a std::string.  To fetch non-POD values, cast to a reference
        // in order to avoid using a constructor from the other class.
        my_variant = std::string("Non-POD std::string");
        std::cout << static_cast<const std::string&>(my_variant) << '\n';

        // store a double value 
        my_variant = 100.001;
        std::cout << static_cast<double>(my_variant) << '\n';

        // now store a char pointer in the same variant object
        my_variant = "Hello!";
        std::cout << static_cast<const char*>(my_variant) << '\n';

        //std::cout << my_variant.stored_type_index << '\n';
        std::cout << '\n';
        std::cout << "union storage size: " << my_variant.sizeof_storage << '\n';
    }
    catch (int type_index) {
        // if the variant's value is fetched with the wrong type conversion,
        // or an attempt is made to store a value not in the parameter pack,
        // an exception is thrown.
        std::cout << "Operation failed: " << type_index << '\n';
    }
}
```