# Q: How to filter a parameter pack with concepts

Tags: c++, metaprogramming, c++-concepts

I'm working on a Entity Component System library with a little part of meta programming. There I have to manage two kind of type : Component type and Manager (data storage) type.

A manager is policies design based and I don't know how many policies they are going to use. A manager can be associated with one or several component.

I have a tuple which contain every component type:

```
template < typename T >
struct FooType {

  using type = T;
};

constexpr auto Components = std::make_tuple(FooType<Foo1>{}, FooType<Foo2>{});
```

So I was going to begin with something like this :

```
template < typename T >
concept bool existingComponent() {
  return true;
}

template < typename ... existingComponent,
           typename ... Policies >
constexpr auto  make_type_pack() {
...
}
```

So I have to replace `true` in the concept by a `constexpr function` which will have to look if the type is inside `Components`. Is that even legal? Sorry I'm new at meta programming and concepts.

Comment: You want to filter a tuple based on whether each type matches a criterion?

Comment: Not really a criterion, I'm just going to check if the type(existingComponent) is inside the component type list.

Comment: Are you looking for a pack/type-list membership test as in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118541/check-if-c0x-parameter-pack-contains-a-type)?