# C++ conditional template member function

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, c++17, sfinae

I am trying to understand how to use `std::enable_if` to choose between 2 functions implementation. In this case, if the type `TupleOfCallback` doesn't contains all the type, it will not compile because `std::get<...>` will throw an error.

For exemple:
`Executor<Entity1*, Entity2*> task([](Entity1 *e){}, [](Entity2 *2){});`

This will not compile because Entity3* is not part of the tuple.

It seem that we can choose between two functions with the same prototype,

```
void Exec(Entity3 *entity)
{
  //enabled when Entity3* is **not** in the tuple
}
```

OR

```
void Exec(Entity3 *entity)
{
  //enabled when Entity3 is in the tuple
  std::get<std::function<void(Entity3*)>>(m_Callbacks)(entity);
}
```

But i dont understand how to achieve this goal.

C++ template mechanism is still hard for me, any help is welcome.

```
template<typename ...T>
class Executor
{
  typedef std::tuple<std::function<void(T)>...> TupleOfCallback;
public:
  Executor(const std::function<void(T)> &...func)
  {
  }

  void Exec(Entity1 *entity)
  {
    std::get<std::function<void(Entity1*)>>(m_Callbacks)(entity);
  }

  void Exec(Entity2 *entity)
  {
    std::get<std::function<void(Entity2*)>>(m_Callbacks)(entity);
  }

  void Exec(Entity3 *entity)
  {
    std::get<std::function<void(Entity3*)>>(m_Callbacks)(entity);
  }

public:
    TupleOfCallback m_Callbacks;
};
```

Comment: C++17 have more options (and simpler syntax) than C++11. Which one do you want?

Comment: Yes i can use c++17, thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can guarantee that all types appear only once, then the following should work:

```
template<typename... Ts>
class Executor {
  using TupleOfCallback = std::tuple<std::function<void(Ts)>...>;
 public:
  Executor(const std::function<void(Ts)>&... func);

  template<class E>
  std::enable_if_t<(std::is_same_v<Ts, E*> || ...)>
  Exec(E* entity) {
    std::get<std::function<void(E*)>>(m_Callbacks)(entity);
  }
  
  template<class E>
  std::enable_if_t<!(std::is_same_v<Ts, E*> || ...)>
  Exec(E* entity) 
  { }

public:
  TupleOfCallback m_Callbacks;
};
```

The basic idea is to use [*fold-expression*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold) to detect whether `E*` is included in `Ts...`, thereby enabling the corresponding function.

[Demo.](https://godbolt.org/z/rhhs1zT8b)

Comment: This solution is exactly what i was looking for. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

Building on this one [Check if parameter pack contains a type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118541/check-if-parameter-pack-contains-a-type). You can use two traits to select which method to call:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

struct Entity1 {};
struct Entity2 {};
struct Entity3 {};

template<typename What, typename ... Args>
struct is_present {
    static constexpr bool value {(std::is_same_v<What, Args> || ...)};
};

template<typename T>
struct is_entity : is_present<T,Entity1,Entity2,Entity3> {};

template <typename T, typename ...Args>
struct is_present_entity {
    static constexpr bool value = is_present<T,Args...>::value && is_entity<T>::value;
};
template <typename T, typename ...Args>
struct is_not_present_entity {
    static constexpr bool value = (!is_present<T,Args...>::value) && is_entity<T>::value;
};


template<typename ...T>
class Executor
{
  
public:
    template <typename U, std::enable_if_t< is_present_entity<U,T...>::value,bool> = true>
    void Exec(U* t){
        std::cout << "foo\n";
    }
    template <typename U, std::enable_if_t< is_not_present_entity<U,T...>::value,bool> = true>
    void Exec(U* t){
        std::cout << "bar\n";
    }
};

struct foo {};

int main(void) {
   Executor<Entity1,Entity2> ex;
   Entity1 e1;
   ex.Exec(&e1);
   Entity3 e3;
   ex.Exec(&e3);
  // foo f;
  // ex.Exec(&f);
}
```

[output](https://godbolt.org/z/57M4r8aK9):

```
foo
bar
```

Answer (score 1):

Another C++17 option:

```
template <typename T>
class ExecutorLeaf
{
public:
  std::function<void(T)> callback;

  void Exec(T entity) { callback(entity); }
};

template <typename... Ts>
class Executor : ExecutorLeaf<Ts>...
{
public:

  Executor(const std::function<void(Ts)>&...funcs) : ExecutorLeaf<Ts>{funcs}... {}

  using ExecutorLeaf<Ts>::Exec...; // C++17
  // Fallback
  template <typename T> void Exec(T) {}
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/ob4bGEo98)

Comment: I like this solution. I have a lot to learn about c++17 ...