# SFINAE for constructing classes with function-type template parameter, based on the type of parameter for the function

Tags: c++, templates, c++14

it's not easy to summarize the topic in a catchy title.

My problem is the following:
I want to call different implementations of a create-function which gives me back a pointer to a callee which is instantiated with a function-type-template-parameter. Those implementations must be selected based on the type_traits of the return- and parameter-types of the function-type-parameter-types.

I have classes with function-type-template-parameters (I hope this is the right expression for that kind of parameter). These are virtual classes which can have different implementations where the call()-function is implemented differently.
So the base-class looks like this:

```cpp
template <typename T> class Callee;

template <typename TReturn, typename... TParams> class Callee<TReturn(TParams...)>
{
public:
    Callee() {}

    virtual TReturn call(TParams... data) = 0;
};
```

The created derived object is registered somewhere and then via an identifier the pointer to the created class as a `Callee<TReturn(TParams...)>*` is passed.
To achieve this and make it a bit easier to use for the developer I made a "Creator"-class which has a static member-function which calls an "internal" function to get the Callee-instance.

So now my point is that we need different implementations of creating stuff based on the types of the parameters of the passed function-type.
I already managed to implement a check if the types of the Parameter pack contain references but I found no other solution than using an additional bool-template parameter. And this is currently used for both `TReturn`and `TParams...` which is also no clean solution.
so now it basically looks like this:

```cpp
template <typename... TParams> class CallerCreator; 

template <typename T, bool containsRef = false> static Callee<T>* createInternal(uint32_t id)
{
    Callee<T>* callee
        = reinterpret_cast<Callee<T>*>(searchCallee(id));

    if (callee == nullptr)
    {
        callee = new OtherCallee<T, containsRef>(id);
    }
    return callee;
}

template <typename TReturn, typename... TParams>
class CallerCreator<TReturn(TParams...)> final
{
public:
    static Callee<TReturn(TParams...)>* create(uint32_t id)
    {
        return createInternal<TReturn(TParams...), contains_reference<TParams...>::value || std::is_reference<TReturn>::value>(id);
    }
};
```

for completeness, the "contains_reference"-implementation (we are using C++14...), which is based on: [Check if parameter pack contains a type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118541/check-if-parameter-pack-contains-a-type)

```cpp
template <typename... List> struct contains_reference : std::true_type
{
};

template <typename Head, typename... Rest>
struct contains_reference<Head, Rest...>
    : std::conditional<std::is_reference<Head>::value, std::true_type, contains_reference<Rest...>>::type
{
};

template <typename Tp> struct contains_reference<Tp> : std::false_type
{
};
```

I also did this for contains_non_trivially_copyable and contains_non_standard_layout.

As you see the `OtherCallee<T, containsRef>` in the snippet, which is created if no Callee is found, I forward the bool to this class since `OtherCallee` can have different implementations based on whether the types contain a reference.
See the static-asserts which I use to "forbid" a creation of this.
But that's not what I want. I just want that the `createInternal`just does not allocate this object then. Just see the implementation as an additional information for completeness but it's not relevant for the problem.
Just imagine `OtherCallee` like this:

```cpp
template <typename T, bool containsRef = false> class OtherCallee;
template <typename TReturn, typename... TParams>
class OtherCallee<TReturn(TParams...), false> : public Callee<TReturn(TParams...)>
{
public:
    explicit OtherCallee(uint32_t id)
    {
        // static_assert(not contains_non_standard_layout<TParams...>::value, "You cannot use non-pod-types!");
        // static_assert(not contains_non_trivially_copyable<TParams...>::value, "You cannot use non-pod-types!");

        // static_assert(std::is_standard_layout<TReturn>::value, "You cannot use non-pod-types!");
        // static_assert(std::is_trivially_copyable<TReturn>::value, "You cannot use non-pod-types!");
    }
    TReturn call(TParams... data) override
    { /* stuff done when no refs */ }
};

template <typename TReturn, typename... TParams>
class OtherCallee<TReturn(TParams...), true> : public Callee<TReturn(TParams...)>
{
public:
    explicit OtherCallee(uint32_t id)
    {
    }
    TReturn call(TParams... data) override
    { /*stuff done when refs (e.g. remove them) */}
}
```

And here again: imagine all other specializations.

My problem is, I just don't want to even create the `OtherCalllee` in case of any of this `static_assert` inside.

Somehow I need different implementations of the `createInternal` function based on the parameter types.
so another `createInternal` should look like this:

```cpp
template <typename T, bool containsRef = false /*, bool returnValIsPod */> static Callee<T>* createInternal(uint32_t id)
{
    Callee<T>* callee
        = reinterpret_cast<Callee<T>*>(searchCallee(id));
    return callee;
}
```

I really have no idea how I can achieve this. I tried passing the `TReturn` and `TParams...` directly for using full specializations, so I can probably use `enable_if` but I don't know how to implement this correctly since I cannot see how I can distinguish whether `TReturn` is `void` or not as well as `TParams...`
The goal would be that I can comment in the `static_assert`s but they will never throw since the implementation of the Constructor will not be called in case of a non-pod-type for `TReturn` or `TParams...`.

I added a minimal example which throws the assert:
https://godbolt.org/z/47oedPsq7

Maybe it's way easier and I just currently don't get it.

Comment: what is the aim? what is the specific question? Sorry, I did read the question, but I neither see the big picture nor the one detail you are currently trying to fix. My suggestion is less text, more [mcve] and include an actual question.

Comment: Same. Why does it matter if there's a reference parameter? Do you just want `if constexpr` in `createInternal`, which would determine if there's a reference either from a `static constexpr bool` member variable in `Callee<T>`, or my writing a separate traits class for function types.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai I added a minimal example. 
I clarified in the comment for the ```createInternal``` that it's about this function which needs to have an additional implementation if the parameter and return types are non-pod.
Not sure how more clearly I can express this question, sorry :/

Comment: @HolyBlackCat yes but as I wrote, we use C++14. if constexpr is a C++17 extension: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if that's why I solved this via template parameters.

Comment: "But that's not what I want. I just want that the createInternal just does not allocate this object then." - saying what you do NOT want is not saying what you want.  I have no idea what you want your `createInternal` to do when the parameter back contains a reference.  If you literally want it to do anything except "allocate an object" that would be one reading (ie, is it ok if it fails to compile if someone tries to use a reference?)  If a non-pod-type is never valid, why do you *want* it to compile?  And if you do, what do you want to happen?

Comment: Also, "Imagine all the other specialization for void types etc." is a red flag.  There should be no specializations for void types, especially in the interface definition.  Writing a good template is often getting your code to work uniformly regardless of what the types are.  You seem to have a desire to fork your implementation based on void/reference/etc details that, in many cases, shouldn't cause forks.  And you aren't being clear what exactly should happen in those forked implementations, which can actually change *how* the forking should be done.

Comment: You might provide solution with C++17 to clarify what is expected.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont I agree. I need different implementations for those template classes since the parameters will be packed and put into memory. Also there is the case where a call needs to wait for an answer as soon as return-type is non-void. and not wait when it is void. For references there must be also a special handling since I do not want to get any references somehow "stored" in memory but the instantiation of the type itself and add references later on again when it is passed. I did not provide those implementations since it did not seem to be relevant for my specific problem.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont And maybe you are right, this was just an example how to generally achieve it. The ```OtherCallee``` should just not be created so the current ```createInternal``` function should not be selected. Since it can happen that the compiler only sees this ```createInternal``` function and always tries to compile the ```OtherCallee``` even with non-allowed types. I want to prevent this compilation to happen in case of non-pod-types but not with an assert but with just not compiling it.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont anyway you are right about the interface. I don't need any other specializations. This was just coming from a legacy-implementation where the Callee was not just an interface... So I will remove this sentence.

Comment: You want it to not work but you don't want it to not work with a static assert?  Static assert halts compilation with a message describing the problem.  You instead want ... a complex pile of template error messages?  A SFINAE friendly failure?  Or your problem is somehow that you are instantiating the code that shouldn't compile and you see the error message as the problem?

Comment: Anyone creating a `CallerCreator<TReturn(TParams...)>` where `TParams...` contains a reference is making an error.  The code should fail to compile and it should break your build; doing so via a static assert is one way.  You seem to see the broken build as the problem; I'd say that problem is the instantiation of `CallerCreator<void(int&)>`.  Making `CallerCreator<void(int&)>` compile and produce nonsense is doable, and appears to be what you are asking, but is probably not what you want.

Comment: Or maybe I misunderstand, and `CallerCreator<void(int&)>` is a valid thing to do?

Comment: Oh wait, I think I see your problem.  `createInternal<TReturn(TParams...), contains_reference<TParams...>::value || std::is_reference<TReturn>::value>(id)` getting rid of syntax issues, and dispatching it to two different implementations.

Comment: I am struggling to understand the whole thing and I still don't get the `Callee<T>*` and the `reinterpret_cast` to it. There seems to be a disconnect somewhere. I was hoping to understand it by starting to implement it (rarely a good idea) but I didn't. I made some simplifications to your meta programming by just copying some example implementations from C++17 though. [example](https://godbolt.org/z/GzrG1Mc4x). With that, you can just do `template <class... Ts> struct contains_reference : std17::bool_constant<std17::disjunction_v<std::is_reference<Ts>...>> {};`

Comment: Hey @TedLyngmo thanks for this addition! I am still getting into template-meta-programming as you see.
The story to the reinterpret_cast is a bit tricky. It's about having the same call-interface for callees on the same core or for callees that are created with the same template-parameters on another core and are sent via IPC. To guarantee the same interface to the user, regardless where the real callee is located, you have different implementations of ```Callee<T>```. and the reinterpret_cast is needed since the other core has no type-information about the received data.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont I feel really sorry for that long way and I am really happy that you were still on it. With your proposed solution you got the problem that I have and how I can solve it, even if it wasn't about the references alone (I should've maybe not added this). 
I also think that it makes no sense to handle a non-pod-type for ```Callee<T>``` differently but we agreed that at least it should then run into a dummy-callee. That's also mainly for tests which are not created at the productive target and thus are not used but share the same code-base.

Answer (score 1):

Use overloading of `createInternal`.

```
template <typename T> static Callee<T>* createInternal(
  std::false_type containsRef, 
  uint32_t id
)
{
  Callee<T>* callee
    = reinterpret_cast<Callee<T>*>(searchCallee(id));

  if (callee == nullptr) {
    callee = new OtherCallee<T, containsRef>(id);
  }
  return callee;
}

template <typename T> static Callee<T>* createInternal(
  std::true_type containsRef, 
  uint32_t id
)
{
  Callee<T>* callee
    = reinterpret_cast<Callee<T>*>(searchCallee(id));

  if (callee == nullptr) {
    // callee = new OtherCallee<T, containsRef>(id);
    // whatever you do when containsRef is true
  }
  return callee;
}
```

then at point of creation:

```
template <typename TReturn, typename... TParams>
class CallerCreator<TReturn(TParams...)> final {
public:
  static Callee<TReturn(TParams...)>* create(uint32_t id) {
    std::integral_constant<bool, contains_reference<TParams...>::value || std::is_reference<TReturn>::value>(id)> containsRef;

    return createInternal<TReturn(TParams...)>(containsRef, id);
  }
};
```

template functions don't support template partial specializations, but do support overloading.

So we stuff the `containsRef` into a function argument and pass it in.  Which every overload `std::true_type` or `std::false_type` matches `containsRef` gets called.

(`std::true_type` is an alias for `std::integral_constant<bool, true>`).

You can use `std::integral_constant` as a compile time value if you need to pass it onto non-type template parameters later, as I did above, but I suspect you won't have to here.

...

There is one more trick you can do, basically back-porting `if constexpr`, where you instantiate and run one of two lambdas based on `true_type` or `false_type` of a parameter.

But you probably don't need that technique.

Comment: I voted up since this answer is really usefull. I wasn't aware of the usage of std::false_type and std::true_type in this manner. that seems to solve the basic problem that I have with distinguishing the function-overloads based on the type traits, references and so on. 
It's not exactly the solution to my problem regarding this non-pod-type But I think I see how I can create a solution here. I will probably update this topic the next time. Thank you really much!